# Background polling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm working on a simple system tray application. It doesn't have any main window but just an icon in the system tray with right-click context menu to (re)start/update a third-party application. It will keep polling a remote location to check if there's a new version available and if so it changes its icon color to inform the user so one can right click then update, the color will change back to normal once the update is completed until another update is detected. The polling process is running all the time until the main application is closed.

The system tray part seems straightforward, what I'm not too sure is what's the best practice about implementing a background polling process, I guess it shouldn't be running on the main/UI thread to block any right click actions. What would be the best option between ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItems, Dispatcher, BackgroundWorker, Task, or async-await (not sure if that fits)

Thanks.

Edit: Polling is not great I totally get that, but in my case it's really inevitable, for example, just imagine it's monitoring a web service by pinging its heartbeat api and it pings every 10 minutes..

Comment: Soooo many things wrong with this. Let's start with... *polling?* *POLLING?!* Please don't run a polling process all the time in the background on my computer, or on anyone else's.

Comment: I know polling is not great, but there's no alternative option here as there's nothing to subscribe to. One poll every 10 minutes won't be the end of the world I guess.. and it's really just for the convenience of a small group of people

Comment: Why don't you (A) let the user update on-demand, and/or (B) check for updates when the user launches the app or otherwise interacts with your process? What in the world are you doing that is so important it has to check for updates every 10 minutes? And what is this thing that you or someone else is going to be pushing updates to every 10 minutes? Why does it need to run constantly even if the user doesn't care about it?

Comment: User can update on-demand that's available in the context menu and yes it will check for updates when the user launchers the app, I don't see anything wrong of it being able to check every 10 minutes and give an indication that something has happened. Imagine it's monitoring a web service by pinging its heartbeat api and it pings every 10 minutes..

Answer (score 1):

To answer the spirit of you question all of the options you mentioned are more or less intended and well suited for various relatively short running jobs that have a defined start and end.  Of the options listed "BackgroundWorker" is the closest fit, but that as well is more intended for a job that can report progress and finishes.  If you really need something that is running all the time through the life of your app then you should probably create and manage a dedicated Thread.

All that being said to Cody's point have you considered just checking on startup? if regular checking is a must setting a Timer that does it on an interval might be a good choice.

Comment: yeah..I also think BackgroundWorker may be a little too much. as I mentioned above, it already does check on startup but a regular check is a must unfortunately..

Comment: then checkout System.Threading.Timer  it should work for what you are trying to do